# Call to a member function getQuery() on null Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have worked a lot with Laravel and never got the following error:

`Call to a member function getQuery() on null` at `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 558`.

I'm trying to get a record with all the relationships specified. The code that is causing that error is the following:

```
        $id = 7;
        $compra = Compra::where('id', $id)
                            ->with(['certificado',
                                    'certificado.duracionServicios', 
                                    'certificado.duracionServicios.servicio', 
                                    'certificado.duracionServicios.servicio.traducciones' => function($query){
                                         $query->whereHas('idiomas', function($q){
                                             $q->where('codigo_region', 'es_MX');
                                         });
                                     },
                                    'user'])
                                    ->first();
```

If I take out the `first()` method, I can print the object instance of `Builder`, but when I try to use it or even use `get()`, that exception is thrown. Laravel version I'm using is 5.5.

Model `Compra`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Compra extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'compras';

    protected $fillable = ['folio',
                            'fecha_compra',
                            'subtotal',
                            'total',
                            'user_id',
                            'direccion_id',
                            ];


    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    /**
     * Get the value of the model's route key.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(config('app.name'), 5);

        return $hashids->encode($this->getKey());
    }


    public function certificado(){
        $this->hasOne('App\Models\Sitio\Certificado', 'compra_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }                   
}
```

Model `Certificado`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Certificado extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'certificados';

    protected $fillable = ['fecha_servicio',
                            'hora_servicio',
                            'compra_id',
                            ];


    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function compra(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sitio\Compra', 'compra_id');
    }

    public function duracionServicios(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Sitio\DuracionServicio', 'certificados_duracion_servicios', 'certificado_id', 'duracion_id');
    }
}
```

Model `DuracionServicio`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DuracionServicio extends Model

{
    protected $table = 'duracion_servicios';

protected $fillable = ['costo',
                        'servicio_id',
                        ];

protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function certificados(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Http\Models\Sitio\Certificado', 'certificados_duracion_servicios', 'duracion_id', 'certificado_id');
}

public function servicio(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sitio\Servicio', 'servicio_id');
}

public function traducciones(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sitio\DuracionServicioTraduccion', 'duracion_id');
}
}
```

Model `Servicio`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servicio extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'servicios';

    protected $fillable = ['seccion_id'];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];


    public function traducciones(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sitio\ServicioTraduccion', 'servicio_id');
    }

    public function duraciones(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sitio\DuracionServicio', 'servicio_id');
    }
}
```

Model `ServicioTraduccion`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ServicioTraduccion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'servicios_traducciones';

    protected $fillable = ['nombre',
                            'descripcion', 
                            'contenido', 
                            'idioma_id', 
                            'servicio_id',
                            ];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function servicio(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sitio\Servicio', 'servicio_id');
    }

    public function idioma(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sitio\Idioma', 'idioma_id');
    }
}
```

Model `Idioma`

```
namespace App\Models\Sitio;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Idioma extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'servicios_traducciones';

    protected $fillable = ['nombre',
                            'codigo_region',
                            ];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    public function servicios(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sitio\ServicioTraduccion', 'idioma_id');
    }

    public function duraciones(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sitio\DuracionServicioTraduccion', 'idioma_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Done, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is in your `Compra` model.

You defined relationship like this:

```
public function certificado()
{
    $this->hasOne('App\Models\Sitio\Certificado', 'compra_id');
}
```

You forgot to add `return`. It should be:

```
public function certificado()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Sitio\Certificado', 'compra_id');
}
```

Comment: But I'm not using using `getQuery()` method :(, that method seems to be executed when using `first()` at a vendor file, I need the model instance that's why I used `first()` method.

Comment: I meant that if I take off the `first()` method, everything runs fine, but I don't want the `Builder` instance, I want the model instance but when I add `first()` method to the chain, then an Exception is thrown.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Sorry, I thought that was the problem. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Heh, shame on me, I just saw the problem on your answer, thank you very much

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez No problem. Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `get_query()` on a `->first()`.

`->first()` will return the first result of your query, and so execute the SQL query (after the `first()` you get a `null` result if no result, or your query result object). You should be able to use `get_query()` or `get()` if you remove the `first()` as you'll have an eloquent query instance, not a result object or collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up a query here by calling the `query()` method first.

```
       $id = 7;
       $compra = Compra::query()->where('id', $id)
        ->with(['certificado',
                'certificado.duracionServicios', 
                'certificado.duracionServicios.servicio', 
                'certificado.duracionServicios.servicio.traducciones' => function($query){
                        $query->whereHas('idiomas', function($q){
                            $q->where('codigo_region', 'es_MX');
                        });
                    },
            'user'])
            ->get();
```

or you can use `->first();`